# Repeated execution after the function complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is essential that in the cycle of repeated request to file test.php carried out after the current response is received

```
Groups = {
  '1': 1214, 
  '2': 1215,
  '3': 1217,
  '4': 1225,
  '5': 1294,
  '6': 1247
}

$.each(Groups, function (index, value) {
    $.get('test.php', {
        'call': value
    }, function (result) {
        $('.console_wrapper').append(result + '<br />');
    });
    // if the result obtained is performed again
    // next 
});
```

Comment: well? what is your question?

Comment: Sooo... what is your question? Edit your post, and state in a clear fashion what is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Object.size = function (obj) {
    var size = 0,
        key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
var Groups = {
        '1': 1214,
        '2': 1215,
        '3': 1217,
        '4': 1225,
        '5': 1294,
        '6': 1247
}
var max = Object.size(Groups); //get size/length of Groups
i = 1;

function get_value(val) {
    $.get('test.php', {
        'call': val
    }, function (result) {
        $('.console_wrapper').append(result + '<br />');
        if (i < max) { //if i is less than max 
            get_value(Groups[++i]); //call function with new value from Group
        }
    });
}
get_value(Groups[i]);
```

Comment: Updated to `++i` in `get_value(Groups[++i]);` instead of `i++` .